# How to change Google Play "displaying achivements" top icon?

Tags: android, icons, google-play

On the following window
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#displaying_achievements
there is a small icon at the side of "Achivements".
It is supposted to be the same as the app but we are getting other result. 
Where is this icon coming from and how can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

We just found that the icon changed after a while. It looks like an older icon that was stored on a cached memory was showing up.